# How to create complex search filters while doing a GET on sales orders through Magento 2 REST API?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I have 12 sales orders which have "store_id" = 1.
Out of which 3 orders have "status" = "pending"

I get all the 12 orders when I make a GET request to http://mystore/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][field]=store_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][value]=1

I want to make a OR search,
I want all the orders for which "store_id" = 1 OR "status" = "pending"
Ideally I should get all the 12 orders, but my following request gets back only 3 orders in response: 
http://mystore/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][field]=store_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][value]=1&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][field]=status&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][value]=pending

I had the knowledge that different filters inside a filter group are merged the OR way. And the filter groups are merged the AND way.

But this is not working.

Even the following request gets 3 orders: 
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=store_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=1&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=status&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=pending

Both filter_groups and filters are being merged the AND way.

Please help.

Assumptions: There are no syntax mistakes in making the request.

Comment: I found an open issue in github of magento2.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3018
Is this the reason?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to set different indexes for filters. The first should be with [filters][0], and the second - [filters][1]?

http://mystore/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=store_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=1&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][field]=status&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][value]=pending

In your case, you use just [filters][1], and you get only condition "status=pending"